# Is there a way to open all git changed files in new tabs in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'd love to be able to review my work and build commits this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bring up the Changes tool window you can select all the files there (you may want to switch off directory grouping), and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. That will open as many of the files as IntelliJ is configured to allow at one time.